# Left-Aligning footnotes in Beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, indentation, footmisc

How can I align the footnote to the left, so that the 'a' from 'aligned' stands directly below the 'T' of 'This'? Using `\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}` "eats" the footnote completely.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame{

Some text\footnote{This is a footnote spanning more than one line, that I would like to be aligned left.}

}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `beamer` redefines many commands; most of the times is better not to use packages, but to redefine the inner commands from `beamer`.

Below, there's one option redefining the inner `\beamer@framefootnotetext` (from `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`) to use a `\parbox` for the footnote text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>\beamer@framefootnotetext[1]{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@footins\vbox{%
    \hsize\framewidth
    \textwidth\hsize
    \columnwidth\hsize
    \unvbox\beamer@footins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \uncover#2{\@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\parbox[t]{.9\textwidth}{#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}\vskip1sp}}%
    \color@endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnote{This is a footnote spanning more than one line, that now after some modifications is aligned left.}
Some other text\footnote{This is another footnote spanning more than one line, that is also aligned left.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]