# Remove footnote indent for Beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I saw this excellent answer [Left-Aligning footnotes in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169745/left-aligning-footnotes-in-beamer), and am curious how to modify this to remove the left indentation on the footnote. I've tried adding `\parindent=0pt` as well as changing `\footnotesep` to `\z@` for zero space to no avail.

Note that [How to remove indentation in footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289108/how-to-remove-indentation-in-footnote) does not work for Beamer.

```latex
% how to get rid of indent?
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>\beamer@framefootnotetext[1]{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@footins\vbox{%
    \hsize\framewidth
    \textwidth\hsize
    \columnwidth\hsize
    \unvbox\beamer@footins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \uncover#2{\@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\parbox[t]{.9\textwidth}{#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}\vskip1sp}}%
    \color@endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnote{This is a footnote spanning more than one line, that now after some modifications is aligned left.}
Some other text\footnote{This is another footnote spanning more than one line, that is also aligned left.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of redefining the footnote, you could simply do something like `\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\hskip -2em}{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\hskip -2em}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text.\footnote{This is a footnote with indent removed.}

Some other text.\footnote{This is a subsequent footnote that is also not indented and spans more than one line.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert negative `\hskip` to `\footnotesep` like this:

```
\hskip -1.5em    
    \color@begingroup
      \uncover#2{\@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\parbox[t]{.9\textwidth}{#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}\vskip1sp}}%
    \color@endgroup}%
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>\beamer@framefootnotetext[1]{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@footins\vbox{%
    \hsize\framewidth
    \textwidth\hsize
    \columnwidth\hsize
    \unvbox\beamer@footins
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
   {\noindent\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \hskip -1.5em    
    \color@begingroup
      \uncover#2{\@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces\parbox[t]{.9\textwidth}{#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}\vskip1sp}}%
    \color@endgroup}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnote{This is a footnote spanning more than one line, that now after some modifications is aligned left.}
Some other text\footnote{This is another footnote spanning more than one line, that is also aligned left.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]